# SQL query completed successfully but not results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2017.
I imported a list of approx 20million emails, just ran the below code to remove any duplicates:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email) AS RN
    FROM dbo.cleanemails
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

It says Query executed successfully, and under the Messages tab says 10million rows affected (expected) but there is no Results tab. 
I am wanting to export into a csv file.
I have check the execution setting as the Parseonly and Noexec settings sometimes cause issues but they were both OFF.

I am relatively new to SQL, any help would be appreciated.
Studio screen shot
[image]
execution settings
[image]

Comment: You are doing a delete, this just deletes records. If you want records shown you need SELECT

Comment: There is no select statement here. You performed a DELETE which does NOT output anything other than the rowcount. What are you expecting for output?

Comment: Next time please upload screenshot with better quality so we can actually see things (the studio screenshot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to view the deleted records, then you can use `OUTPUT` clause

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY email
                    ORDER BY email) AS RN
         FROM   dbo.cleanemails)
DELETE FROM CTE
output deleted.*
WHERE  RN <> 1
```